# How to remove characters that are not in ASCII range 32 - 126 from a column in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table containing two columns which can hold any character values. However the target system only allows characters in the ASCII range 32 - 126.
My requirement is to remove the characters out of this ASCII range, and allow others to flow

Ex : Frédéric should become Frdric - which just drops all spl chars out of that range.

It should only be within a query, not a procedure. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function?

Two basic examples could be:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Frédéric', '[^ -~]', '') FROM dual;
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('QuÉbec', '[^ -~]', '') FROM dual;
```

Generates the output:

[image]

The second parameter, or the regexp portion inside the `[]` set is:
 <kbd>^</kbd> Not
<kbd>space</kbd> single space
<kbd>-</kbd> hyphen
<kbd>~</kbd> tilde

Which means that any characters that are not <kbd>^</kbd> in the range of <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> (space to tilde) get replaced by the `''` empty string.

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0b09ca97cd768b5d84d730fd5d449c57) for the image examples.

Note that I also tried using the `'[^[:print:]]'` character class, which covers the same range, but it does not seem to work.